# Logout and Clear GoogleAPIclient in Async Task

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, google-api-client

I have code which is working fine for logout of google apiclient, but it left one activity opened after execution, either can some one tell where should I put finish(); to kill that activity or how can I do whole thing in async task. I tried to do with async but got error as client not connected.

Here is code for logout with class extending to activity:

```
public class GoogleDriveLogoutBackup extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
private static final String TAG = "drive-quickstart";
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    Log.d("Connected","Here");
    mGoogleApiClient.clearDefaultAccountAndReconnect();
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
      }
}
```

And here is code which I m using for Async class which I giving me error:

```
public class GoogleDriveLogout extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
private static final String TAG = "drive-quickstart";
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Context mcontext;

public GoogleDriveLogout(Context context) {
    this.mcontext = context;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mcontext)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
                .build();
    }

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}


@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Log.d("Connected", "Here");
    mGoogleApiClient.clearDefaultAccountAndReconnect();
    return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I able to did it now by using calling ApiClientAsyncTask which is provided by google itself.